# I can only launch Fallout 4 once after I start my computer. Why?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, fallout-4

I can only run Fallout 4 once after a fresh reboot. If I close the game and launch it again it crashes after pressing play in the launcher.

The only way to launch it again is to restart my computer and wait a few seconds after Steam launches.

I have a hunch that the game launchers a process that does not close properly (is running in the background) and the only way to kill it is to reboot.

I tried logging off and on again but that did not help, a hard restart is always needed.

I looked at the windows logs but nothing useful came up.

> PC specs:  Win 10 64bit, Intel Pentium anniversary edition, 16GB ram,
>   ssd disk, AMD 6850 GPU

How can I fix this?

Comment: I tried killing a few processes but it did not help. And logging off should kill all user processes.

Comment: Seems strange. PC configuration, tell me.

Comment: Win 10 64bit, Intel Pentium anniversary edition, 16GB ram, ssd disk, AMD 6850 GPU - the game works fine the first time a launch

Comment: Computer seems more than enough for smooth gameplay. I don't have an answer, sorry.

Comment: Try ending explorer. Also, try the real exe instead of the launcher.

Comment: Do you have any updates installed for the game?

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136901158185/ Moe people report the same issue here, one person says they can launch 2x if they switch from fullscreen to window mode, chances are it has something to do with that staying open some way

Comment: I always play Fallout 4 in borderless windowed mode. Switching does not help at all. And people report the same issue on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s5ga4/fallout_4_crashes_on_start_up_pc/

Comment: I am running version 1.3 but had a similar issue on 1.2 - I could not launch the game properly, it took me several tries (at least 5) to launch the game successfully.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already updated Windows, Steam, Fallout 4 and GPU drivers.

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 auto updates everything, even tried beta AMD drivers.

Comment: Have you tried running the game in windows 7 compatibility mode? Actually, thinking about it steam launches games using custom URIs instead of being an .lnk. Secondly, have you tried verifying game files?

Comment: Game files verified and ok

Comment: Check that Fallout4.exe (or FalloutIV, I forgot) is not running in the background. Use the task manager.

Comment: It is not, as the game syncs saved games with steam after I close it.

Comment: Having the same issue as OP but it only started mid-June 2016. Maybe something patched? Works fine after reboot but certainly a pain to deal with.

Comment: @DenverLMartin I actually can't start the game at all since last week now. I wonder if I will have the same problem after the enhanced eddition of Skyrim comes out.

Comment: You have already tried validating your game cache, reinstalling the game, reinstalling Steam, etc.? And to clarify, you are not running any mods, correct?

Comment: "Windows 10 auto updates everything" That's a giant red flag. Even if that's not part of the current problem, it will be. "Maybe something patched?" indeed. Don't let things that work, arbitrarily update themselves except for Steam itself and your OS. Games that aren't online and your video drivers should not.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen a few times on several Steam applications. Typically, this happens when the actual process fails to close properly or hangs in the close process (i.e. if you close the application through the task bar rather than through steam or its native launcher from within steam...) and when there's a memory leak where, if you open task manager you can see how much memory is being used to run the process.

You'll likely notice a disproportionate amount of RAM being used on the specific application you're unable to reopen.

You'll need to kill that, any steam associated process altogether, and any Fallout 4 application specific process (helpers, the exe, etc).

Then check for video driver updates, game updates, and steam updates - but it's usually the result of how you're closing out and less a problem between the systems deployed.

Comment: Restarting Steam until it stops updating itself every time usually works for me for most problems. Killing process is the next step. Be sure you "Show processes from all users"

Answer (score -3):

Uninstall Fallout and Steam and then reinstall Steam and re-download Fallout. Steam should have saved your progress (if you had any) when you log in again.

Comment: Seems worth a try